# Rename Colnames from dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I am making a Shiny App and I would like to rename the first variable from dataframe, to make after a corrplot.

In normal R the code is:

```
library(lares) 

names(Dataset)[1] <- "DR"
corr_var(Dataset, DR, top=20)
```

And in Shiny I have something:

```
 dataReg2 = reactive({
        inFile <- input$fileReg
        if (is.null(inFile))
          return(NULL)
        else 
          data1 = read_excel(inFile$datapath)
        return(data1)
      })

 plot=reactive({
        names(dataReg2())[[1]]='DR'
        corr_var(dataReg2(), DR , top = 20 )
      })
```

But it doesn't work, the error is `invalid (NULL) left side of assignment`...
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the column names of reactive object. Copy the data in another variable and you can change the column name of that variable. See this simple example using `mtcars`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput('tab')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive(mtcars)
  
  output$tab <- renderTable({
    new_table <- data()
    names(new_table)[1] <- 'new'
    head(new_table)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```